# node not printing full object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm stumped..

I tested this method with another object that contains a nested array in the console, and got the expected results

```
db_status_emitter.on("components_found", function (returned_item) {
    //console.log(returned_item);
    prun_item.type = returned_item.type;
    prun_item.components = returned_item.components.slice(0);
    switch (prun_item.type) {

        case "one-sided-mattress":

            prun_item.quantity = prun_item.total_panel_quantity;
            var top_panel = underscore.find(prun_item.components, function (element) {
                return element.component_category == "top-panel"
            });
            var border = underscore.find(prun_item.components, function (element) {
                return element.component_category == "border"
            });
            top_panel.quantity = border.quantity = prun_item.quantity;
            top_panel.style = "91000000";
            border.style = "81000000";
            break;

        case "two-sided-mattress":

            prun_item.quantity = prun_item.total_panel_quantity / 2;
            var top_panel = underscore.find(prun_item.components, function (element) {
                return element.component_category == "top-panel"
            });
            var bottom_panel = underscore.find(prun_item.components, function (element) {
                return element.component_category == "bottom-panel"
            });
            var border = underscore.find(prun_item.components, function (element) {
                return element.component_category == "border"
            });
            top_panel.quantity = bottom_panel.quantity = border.quantity = prun_item.quantity;
            top_panel.style = "91000000";
            bottom_panel.style = "92000000";
            border.style = "81000000";
            break;

        default:
            console.error("error with prun Schedule");
            break;
    }
    console.log(prun_item);
});
```

//**EDIT**: I should add the mongoose call here; it's in the same scope, as the .on() function... I

```
fex_model.findOne({_id: prun_item.model}, {components: 1, type: 1, _id: 0}, function (err, returned_item){
    if (err) db_status_emitter.emit("error", err)
    db_status_emitter.emit("components_found", returned_item);
})
```

why are none of the components displaying the added key value pairs I have given them? Here's a sample of the output..

```
{ quilter_name: 'Panel Quilter #3',
schedule_no: 55f32e4470df49a65d03cf6a,
model: '3630',
size: '66',
total_panel_quantity: 72,
type: 'two-sided-mattress',
components: 
 [ { component_category: 'top-panel', buffer_op: '120' },
   { component_category: 'bottom-panel', buffer_op: '120' },
   { component_category: 'border', buffer_op: '119' } ],
quantity: 36 }
```

but it should be:

```
{ quilter_name: 'Panel Quilter #3',
schedule_no: 55f32e4470df49a65d03cf6a,
model: '3630',
size: '66',
total_panel_quantity: 72,
type: 'two-sided-mattress',
components: 
 [ { component_category: 'top-panel', buffer_op: '120', quantity: 36, style: "91000000" },
   { component_category: 'bottom-panel', buffer_op: '120', quantity: 36, style: "92000000" },
   { component_category: 'border', buffer_op: '119', quantity: 36, style: "81000000" } ],
quantity: 36 }
```

but why on earth does the same process work on the console???

```
>underscore.extend(extended_this_object, components_wrapper);
{ foo: 'bar',
  components: 
   [ { a: 'findthis', b: '3', c: '4', d: 'new value' },
     { a: 'notthis', b: '4', c: '5' } ] }
>var foundthis2 = underscore.find(extended_this_object.components, function(element){ return element.a == 'findthis'});

>foundthis2
{ a: 'findthis', b: '3', c: '4', d: 'new value' }
>foundthis2.e = 'a newer value'
'a newer value'
>extended_this_object;
{ foo: 'bar',
  components: 
   [ { a: 'findthis',
       b: '3',
       c: '4',
       d: 'new value',
       e: 'a newer value' },
     { a: 'notthis', b: '4', c: '5' } ] }
```

**EDIT** Here's the output of the keys for a single component..I suspect it has to do with it coming from mongoose...

```
[ '__parentArray',
  '__parent',
  '__index',
  '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_doc',
  '$__original_save',
  'save',
  '_pres',
  '_posts',
  'quantity',
  'style' ]
```

notice that quantity and style are attributes on their own, and the logged attributes, I suspect, are somewhere in _doc.

Comment: To avoid such confusion, you should refactor your assignment. Could you also re-indent your code? It's not easy to read.

Comment: what do you mean by refactor my assignment? :( 

also, when re-indenting, should there be more whitespace (newlines)?  or 8 spaces instead of 4 between indents?

Comment: You can use the TidyUp from JSFiddle to re-indent, that's enough, it would be much easier to read.
Refactor is the action to reorganize your code. Use a function to handle those data.

Comment: in your *EDIT* above make a call toObject() to avoid those mongoose unwanted properties like '__parentArray'   :    for (var curr_key in  user.toObject()) {

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this was an interesting problem, but then I realized it makes no sense. I tried doing various similar things in a js file and `node`ing it but I can't replicate what you encountered.

Either the log message doesn't come from the `console.log`, or that this problem can't be replicated after restarting the server (something went wrong in V8 for a moment?).

Have you tried changing the log arugment to something like `prun_item.components[0].quantity`?

Or perhaps your original code is a lot more complex than this and modifying the object returned from `_.find` does not modify the object that you `console.log`, which is the only logical explanation for this.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head. Mongoose returns an array of objects with a bunch of properties that I'm not really supposed to mess with. I was slicing that and trying to alter it by using a reference. Bad idea. I'll reword the question later and provide a solution so that it may be of use to folks who may end up doing the same thing.